# Correctly use of a python code as a module

Tags: python, import, module, typeerror

I have a python code, say **first.py**, that call, during his execution a second one, say **second.py**.
**second.py** is used as a big function that return back a certain object.
In particular, the structure of **first.py** is the following (where `...` indicate a part of the code not relevant (where I define the variable to give in input for example)):

```
import second as nb
...
x = nb.BP(a, b, c)
...
```

While the structure of **second.py** is the following:

```
def BP (A, B, C)
...
    return obj
```

Now, in my working folder, say **MainFold** , I have this 2 code. Inside **MainFold** there is also another folder, say **SubFold**. Inside **SubFold** I have a modified version of **first.py** and **second.py** which mantain the same names.
The difference in these codes is that the function BP inside  **second.py** now takes only 2 arguments.
I start running the **first.py**'s **MainFold** version. Then, I launch the version inside **SubFold**. What I get is a TypeError:

```
TypeError: BP() missing 1 required positional arguments: 'C'
```

It seems like the varied version of  **first.py** inside **SubFold** calls the **second.py**'s version inside **MainFold** instead of the code inside its folder (**SubFold**).
Why does it happens? Is there a way to force **first.py** to call only codes inside its same folder?

Comment: I think the problem is the name. Just give them another name, it's a better practice ;)

Comment: Use a different name fix the problem but I don't understand why this happens. How does it work the colling of a second code from the first one? why does it call a code with the same name but in a different folder instead the one in the same folder?

Comment: you imported the file, so python now has 2 options for that name. It doesn't care about what file it's from ;)

Answer (score 2):

When you try to import a module that is in the same folder simply write:

```py
import second as nb
```

To access the files from the subfolder use:

```py
import subfolder.second as nb
```

Comment: Thank you akopcz; is it possible to do the same thing without specifing the name of the folder (only indicate that it has to access the file in his same folder, without specifing the name of the folder)?

Comment: If you don't specify the parent folder of the file (in the subdirectory), python is going to assume that the file is in the same folder. Import the module you want to use and don't import the other.

Comment: akopcz this is what I expected to see, but as you can see from my question the code inside **SubFolf** import the module contained in the higher **MainFold** folder. This point isn't clear for me

Comment: You may have a problem with something else then which file is imported. If you want to import the files from the main folder from the subfolder, you either have to work with relative imports or you have to append the main folder to the `sys.path`. Otherwise, the files from the same directory will be imported.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the path to the folder:

1. Let's say you are in subfold and the program is second.py
2. then give it address as "/subfold/second.py"

Try this if the error persists, ping me again!